# Calculate to see if Top 20 Items in current year > Grand Total of Previous Year

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on creating a report that will compare the top 20 items by Total Quantity in the Current Year and see if it exceeds the Grand Total of All Items from the previous year. I am unsure how to put this report together, what parameters i may need or the calculations so i step by step would be very helpful.

Comment: are you performing further calculation after comparing both values

Comment: @Siva, i am not. i only want to a graph that compares the top 20 products by Sum(QTy) of the current year and compare it to all of the products by Grand Total Qty and see if the current years top 20 products exceed 20% of the grand total of the products from the previous year.

Comment: sure will let you know solution'

Comment: @Siva any update on this?

Comment: Yeah working on your issue will post answer today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to achieve the required graph.

Follow below process:

You need use fixed LoD to get the previous year sales (All customers) and dimension filter for the data for top 20 customers.

Create a calculated field and write below code for previous year grand total with 20% of total sales.

```
{ FIXED :SUM(IF YEAR([Order Date])=YEAR(DATEADD('year',-1,[Order Date])) THEN ([Sales]) END)}*0.2
```

Now create a calculated field and write below code for current year and place the field in filter and select `true` to get current year data

Current year

```
YEAR([Order Date])=Year(Today())
```

Now create a set and select Top 20 customers and drop set on to filters

Place year, sales and previous year grand total on to report and then select `Line` for previous year total and `Bar` for current year and then use dual axis and finally Syncronize axis

Let me know if it works also if you need I can share you work book

[image]

Comment: this is not working for me. could you send me a screenshot of your screen so i can see how you put it together? it is not seeming to work.